# Custom bindingHandlers did not trigger 'value change' of my input element

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following bindingHandlers which allows me to format my dates:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateRW = {
    //dateRW --> the 'read-write' version used both for displaying & updating dates
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            var myDate = moment($(element).val(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
            observable(myDate.toDate());
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();  // 'Mon Sep 10 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))'; 
        var date = (typeof value() !== 'undefined') ? moment(value()) : null;
        var dateFormatted = (date != null) ? date.format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
        $(element).val(dateFormatted);
    }
};
```

Example of use:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="dateRW: myDate" />
```

It works but whenever I edit the input element I need to click outside (lost focus) of the element for triggering `value change`. I already try `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` but it doesn't work. I know `valueHasMutated` exists but I don't know if this must be done.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

As suggested, I try to use the `keyup` event. I remind that my only goal is to 'simulate' that value has changed in the keyup event.

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function () {
    observable($(element).val());
});
```

With this implementation the problem is the `update` on the bindingHandlers will be triggered for each key pressed. This will result often in invalid dates. Example: the user will type a new date in the input field one digit at a time. For each digit the update is triggered and new content of the input is badly interpreted.

I also try this:

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function () {
    observable.notifySubscribers($(element).val());
});
```

With this implementation the problem is the `update` on the bindingHandlers will be triggered but reusing the current value behind the observable and because this is already the value in the input no changes is detected.

I also try to use the `valueHasMutated` but I always got an error because my dependantObservable does not have this method.

**My goal is to display my `Save changes` button whenever the user begin to change the date BUT really update the date in the input field only when he leaves focus (the change event)**

Comment: You can try to register handler for `keyup` event instead of `change`.

Answer (score 0):

The `valueUpdate` option only applies to the `value` binding, so it would not help you in this case.

You would likely want to handle both the `change` event and another event like `keyup` or `keydown`.

Also, in your `update` function calling `valueAccessor()` gives you back your observable and not the  value that it holds.  You would want to call the result as a function or use the `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` utility that safely returns the value for both observables and non-observables.  Unwrapping the observable will also create a dependency, so that programmatic updates to the value will trigger the `update` function again to update your value.